# HTML\JS - Table pagination by column

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, pagination

There are lots of libraries that offer great performance on huge data sets for "standard" tables - (with 5-10 columns and thousands of rows), but my use-case requires a reversed appproach: there are not so many rows (~10) and thousands of columns.

Is there a library that can performantly handle thousands of columns? Or a library that offers a column-wise pagination?